# Localization iOS doesn't work correctly

Tags: ios, localization

I have a problem with the localization, it must be in `English` and `Italian`. I'm using `NSLocalizedString`, but I have a problem.

If I set the language to `Italian` or English everything works correctly. If I set any other language it remains `Italian`. But if I first set the language to `English` and then to `Spanish` for example, at this point will remain in `English`. In the `plist` file "localized native development region" is set to `English`.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fallback language is the **first language** in `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]` that is supported by the app. It is **not always** English. If you change the language in the `Settings` it will move to the top of the list.

Comment: so i can't do anything for this? i'd like if the user isn't italian, run the application in english

Comment: Not if you are using `NSLocalizedString`. You would need to implement a custom solution. This thread sheds some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593561/custom-nslocalizedstring

Comment: ok thanks! i can get the language through NSUsersDefaults and set a condition, if language is equal to italian set italian word, else set english word. Could be a solution?

Comment: Yes, correct. But to get current language just use `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];` and not `NSUsersDefaults`.