# iOS: Is it possible to override the locale set on the phone and make it use a strings for a different locale?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

In iOS, is it possible to override the locale currently set on the phone and make it use a strings for a different locale in my app?

Comment: In production or development?

Comment: @JuJoDi Both prod and dev.

Answer (score 5):

In short: **Yes.**

The `NSLocalizedString` is a macro, which you can replace with your own macro and do the language loading yourself. This might require setting most of the strings in code though and you will not be able to use them in Storyboards.

However, changing the locale manually in `NSUserDefaults` works if you want to change the locale.

The answers below explain more on this topic:

- [Custom NSLocalizedString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593561/custom-nslocalizedstring)
- [change locale programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022628/change-locale-programmatically)
- [Change app language programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207986/change-app-language-programmatically)
- [iOS: How to change app language programmatically WITHOUT restarting the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9416923/ios-how-to-change-app-language-programmatically-without-restarting-the-app)

Comment: I appreciate you answering the question with multiple posts rather than downvoting it or marking it as dupe.  Very helpful!